# run selenium scripts NOT in parallel

Tags: java, xml, selenium

I'm new with selenium.  I'm trying to run my suite from a batch file that calls my testng.xml file.  In my xml I want to list all the scripts I want to run, but I want them all to go in sequence only.  I need to define this behavior in the xml tags themselves (say, the suite tag). Please point me in the right direction.  My testng.xml is below:

```
<suite name="Automation-Suite group_58-63-67 " parallel="none">     

<test name="Test56" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="Add_Client.Add_Client_Group_Testcase56"/><!-- End Test56-->
    </classes>
</test> <!-- End Test56-->

<test name="Test57" preserve-order="true">

    <classes>
      <class name="Add_Client.AddClientAdmin_Testcase57"/><!-- End Test57-->
    </classes>
</test> <!-- End Test57-->
```

Comment: make `parallel="none"` and remove `thread-count="1"` and then try

Comment: I've tried that, but I'm still getting them both running at the same time.  I can run them both separately from Eclipse, but when running them via testng.xml, they want to go simultaneously.  I've looked around but can't find an answer to it.

Comment: remove preserve-order="true"

Comment: How would changing the `preserve-order` attribute possibly help in this case? From the docs: By default, TestNG will run your tests in the order they are found in the XML file. If you want the classes and methods listed in this file to be run in an unpredictible order, set the `preserve-order` attribute to `false`. [Link](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)

Comment: I have no clue how your tests are annotated, but sequential is the default behavior, so removing the parallel attribute should achieve what you want. Also, `parallel="none"` is not a legit value. It accepts `methods|tests|classes`. Please consult the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)

Comment: I'm confused about that one too Erki.

My issue is that I was handed a bunch of code someone else wrote (he's gone now) and I need this stuff to run in a clear, sequential way - but just 1 test at a time.  Otherwise, the test results are unpredictable.  Any thoughts from a selenium wiz out there?